# Does MySQL Workbench autocomplete work?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

Using [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), when I press CTRL + space it looks like there is an autocomplete feature (However, no items appear in the auto complete box).

I am not sure that MySQL workbench has an autocomplete feature like [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) has(See screen-shot).

[image]

So if MySQL Workbench really has an intellisense or autocomplete like feature then how I can get them?

Is there any way to make MySQL Workbench auto complete the same way as Sqlyog does?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Auto-completion is not available yet, it's planned for MySQL Workbench version 6.

See http://wb.mysql.com/?p=229#comment-1250

Comment: Version 5.2.47 has a working autocompletion, tried and tested. It should have been available since 5.2.41 [see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-main-menu.html) but for some reason, in my last version that i had (5.2.44) the aut-completion did not suggest column names. Now also column names are suggested and auto-completed.

Comment: Version 6.1.7 autocompletion seems to be not working at all. I already selected Edit > Preferences > SQL Editor > Automatically start code completion but it remains without action when I press Ctrl+Space key combination. For instance, pop-up only appears when I digit "select * from ", just after pressing space bar, allowing me select a table name, but no more.

Comment: I'm on version 6.2 and it's not working for me at all. Instead, every time it opens, it interrupts me and I have to press `ESC` to get out of it again, In fact, I came here looking for ways to turn it off. :(

Comment: I'm on version 6.3 and now autocomplete works - for ONE table/alias only. If this is Oracle's strategy to put people off MySQL and return to Oracle, you've succeeded.

Answer (score 7):

If the autocomplete feature does not suggest table or column names, try deleting the cache files of the specific connections from the MySQL Workbench cache located on:

- Windows: %AppData%\MySQL\Workbench\cache\
- OS X: ~username/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/cache/
- Linux: ~username/.mysql/workbench/cache/

More details about the configuration files can be found on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-configuring-files.html

No matter the MySQL Workbench version (6.2.3, 6.2.5, 6.3.4), in my case the autocompletion was working but did not include table or column names.

After noticing that this happened only on some of the connections, I deleted the cache files and it started working again.

Comment: This halfway resolved my autocomplete problems for both my 5.2.47 and 6.3.6 workbench installs. Column names can be auto-completed on the SELECT line, but I can't seem to get them to be auto-completed in a JOIN ON phrase.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Using mysql workbench 6.3.6

Comment: This didn't work for me in version 8.0 
Is there more than one location for that cache folder?

Answer (score 5):

It now does, as of yesterday (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-news-5-2-41.html). Although it still only provides basic code completion.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where the mysql workbench intellisense worked, but did not show the column names. I followed the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37862473/1500224

It didn't work until I typed `mydatabase` and hit a dot  (`select * from mydatabase.`) and suddenly it started working.