# exists any autocomplete software for mysql?

Tags: mysql, user-interface, autocomplete

I am looking for a software or plugin that's permits a auto-complete for mysql code

For example i write `SEL` and the program suggests `SELECT`.

Something similar to the java auto-complete in eclipse.

In the mysql workbench exists that option? i did ctrl+space but no suggestions appears in the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is something like this:

http://www.taurensys.com/index.html

It isn't free ($150) but it seems to do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: if it were open source or at least free ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **HeidiSQL**

http://www.heidisql.com/

It also suggests Table names and field names apart from MySQL Keywords.

The Auto Suggest feature is not available in MySQL Workbench yet.
Seems Its planned for MySQL Workbench version 6.

See [Does MySQL Workbench autocomplete work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483304/how-mysql-workbrench-autocomplete-works)

Comment: And HeidiSQL is Open Source but only available for Wiondows. I use it in my Ubuntu with Wine.

Comment: HeidiSQL auto-complete for MySQL works like a charm. It works with table aliasing as well. Your answer should be the accepted answer!